# How to integrate contact us section in our web site?

Tags: html, web, dhtml, href

Hi how to give links to these contacts

Skipe

MSN

AIM

For skipe I give like this "skype:shob83?call" but its not working :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for msn

```
<a href="msnim:chat?contact=userid">msn</a>
```

for skype

```
<a href="skype:userid?chat">skype</a>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. For MSN. Now me use like this
msnim:chat?nibos@hotmail.com its working

Answer (score 1):

for skype try this

```
<a href="skype:echo123?call">Click</a> (make a call to echo123)

<a href="skype:echo123;apples123;pears123?call">Click</a> (make a conference call to echo123, apples123 and pears123)

<a href=”skype:user1?chat”> (Start a text chat with user1)

<a href=”skype:user1;user2;user3?chat”>(Start a multichat with 3 people)
```

Answer (score 1):

AIM
`<a href="aim:goim?screenname=notarealuser">Send Message</a>`